# javascript canvas webpage not displaying

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a canvas with a black square and a moving white circle but it is not working and i dont know why here is the issue it is just an empty webpage when i try to open it. I have saved and evreything. i really need help! here is the code

```
<html>
<head>

<title>paddle</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
 <script>
 var canvas
 var canvasContext
 var ballX = 5
 window.onload = function() {

var fps = 30;
setInterval(updateAll, 1000)
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d")

}
function updateAll() {

ballX++
canvasContext.fillStyle = "black"
canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
canvasContext.beginPath()
canvasContext.arc(ballX, 100, 10, 0, Math.PI*2 true);
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you ever get stuck, just hit F12 on all modern browsers running on desktops, laptops, and the like. This will bring up Dev Tools and a console that will show the error and where in the code it is. Very useful for typos and syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma before the last argument here (between `Math.PI*2` and `true`):

```js
canvasContext.arc(ballX, 100, 10, 0, Math.PI*2 true);
```